# Unable to send text to another iPhone on same account

Tags: iphone, messages, sms

I'm having issues sending messages/texts to my to wife's iPhone but she can send them to my iPhone and they show up with my ID?

Can anyone tell me why and how I can fix it?

Comment: My local providers allows up to five sim cards for a single provider account/contract. You can only use one to receive messages. Maybe these limitations apply to you, too...

Answer (score 4):

To address this issue I'd recommend checking the iMessage settings on both phones. If they're both using the same Apple ID for iMessage, they may have trouble sending to each other. Changing the iMessage Apple ID will not mess up anything else (like the Store, iCloud, etc).

To check it, go to **Settings** > **Messages** > **Send & Receive**

A button at the top of that screen will show you which Apple ID is being used for iMessage. If they're the same on both phones, you'll need to sign out on the one you wish to change. To do this, tap the "Apple ID: " button and then choose **Sign Out**.

[image: Screenshot of iMessage settings]

Then you'll be able to sign in to iMessage with a different Apple ID, existing or new. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thx, neither is set to use an Apple ID, both are set to receive at their respective phone numbers

Comment: Hm... so I guess you're not using iMessage at all. 

If her messages to you appear as if they're *from **you***, check to see if you have somehow saved her number as your number. If you have, that would explain why you can't send messages to her ... you can't send messages to yourself.

Comment: If you try sending one to her by manually typing her number in your Messages app, do you still experience the issue?

Comment: I too couldn't send any messages. Your tip helped. I went to settings & turned off iMessages, turned it back on & logged in. Now it works - Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this occurs because the device might not contain iMessage, eg. iPhone 3GS

Comment: Good point! An edge case, but something to consider.